# When is bolding considered unnecessary?

Tags: discussion, formatting

In the following example question, bolding was removed as unnecessary:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65685587/revisions

The bolding was added so that by just reading the bold part you get a feeling what the question is about:

> docker-based [..] default project and token [..] from a file or environment variables [..] do not need ui for setting them.

The bolding was completely removed as unnecessary?

Is the above style of writing questions or answers wrong?

Should I avoid bolding parts of a sentence, just to make a question or answer easily readable?

Comment: It is a question of style as to whether or not bolding makes a text more readable. Speaking for myself, I could _really_ do without the bolding.

Comment: In that example, it was bolding keywords, which I (personally) don't think are needed. Bold adds an extra *stress* on the word, its add emphasis, so I only really see it's needed when you do need to emphasis something. Emphasising the technology in the middle of a sentence isn't needed, in my opinion; we have tags for that.

Comment: I, honestly, think I find myself using bold text in comments more than anything. For example, when a user goes and tags 4 completely different RDBMS (which really confuses matters, and can easily make the question unanswerable) I'll often write a comment along the lines of "Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS." (and remove all the RDBMS tags). I add emphasis on only, to emphasise that they should only be using the tag for their RDBMS, and not random other ones.

Comment: **Most** of the time. I use it when I would really emphasise a word when reading it out loud to someone. And that would be the scope for bolding - single words.

Comment: Does the downvoting mean that I should not have placed the question or that I should remove it?

Comment: If you have too much bold, you don't have bold. It's supposed to **draw attention** to something. Adding too much of means that everything is important, thus nothing is really important. If the intention is for only the bold parts to be readable as some sort of summary...then that suggests that everything between them is unnecessary. If I have to read the bold text once to see if I am interested then I still have to re-read it with the unbolded parts to actually understand it, then the writing style is implicitly unclear.

Comment: I simply found it was unnecessary and actually distracts. You don't need to emphasize on every other aspects because otherwise it'll be just noise and I will be more willing to skip those bold parts rather than reading them.

Comment: Down vote = disagreement. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Downvotes might mean that some users find the question not useful or that is poorly researched.

Comment: Hi Marinos, I downvoted and want to explain why: The question is valid but I immensely hate overly bolded text and want to express that opinion. Keep in mind, votes on meta do not change your reputation and are different from normal SO. Also, I appreciate it that you came to Meta instead of engaging in an edit war.

Comment: I fail to see how "docker-based" "default project and token" "from a file or environment variables" "do not" "ui for setting them" gives a feeling of what the question is about. There does not seem to be any actual question, as in a clear technical problem to solve and the issue with that, in it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find this a good question worth asking. It's better to ask than to let the uncertainty put the wrong ideas in your head. But I can't help but wonder if you really do not see any problem with excessive bolding yourself? Imagine that bold words are spoken out loud or even shouted, the pre-edited state of the question starts to sound cartoonish then, doesn't it?

Comment: @Gimby "bold words are spoken out loud or even shouted". Do you have a reference for this? Because i could equally imagine that they are just spelled at a different voice tone or style.

Comment: I really appreciate answers that use phrases like "I think" and "presonally" rather that expressing certainty, since no one has posted any link to a specification or English syntax rules defining how to use bold.

Comment: @MarinosAn which style guide did you consult with that advised you adding bold markup to those particular words is more easily readable?

Comment: @VLAZ [This tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers) for example, which in my opinion uses bolding to save reader's time (and which I not find destructive). Though I never claimed that this style is the source of truth.

Comment: Seems quite different to your text. Also, a lot more sparingly used as it's one key idea per paragraph, not even every paragraph. Bolding "docker-based" followed by "default project and token" does not form a coherent piece of information the reader can quickly skim.

Comment: @VLAZ "does not form a coherent piece of information the reader can quickly skim". I agree. I see it more clearly now. So from many of the answers I conclude that, for the last question, a possible answer is: "yes, unless it is used sparingly enough to not confuse the reader"

Answer (score 21):

> *"When is bolding considered unnecessary?"*

Almost always. Use formatting like that *very* sparingly. As a rule of thumb, I try to avoid bolding text more than once in a question / answer

Bold text comes across as "screaming" / distracting / obnoxious. It's also generally redundant, as every reader has their own way to scan over text.

I, for one, don't consider that amount of bold text "more readable".

Comment: “Bold text comes across as "screaming" / distracting / obnoxious. It's also generally redundant, as every reader has their own way to scan over text.” - I can get around the fact it’s perhaps distracting or obnoxious but I cannot get behind it’s screaming since that’s what an **exclamation mark** actually means.  Yes; This comment is being slightly ironic by bolding those two words.   By doing I am being obnoxious not screaming :$

Comment: I think of it more as an **invasive emphasis**. I am **pushing these words** into your attention. I want you to take these words **by force**. **Ingest** them.

Answer (score 21):

Think of it like this:

A lot of people interpret and read things with either italics or bold text in a different way, or with more emphasis or impact.  Unless you *require* that in the course of asking a question or answering a question, there is no reason to include the extra emphasis.

Pretend that you're talking to another person in the same room and use the same emphasis that the question has.  Are they going to understand what you're saying or are they going to be slightly irked with the intonation that you're giving them, with all of the emphasis in odd and unconventional places?

Comment: Perfect example.

Answer (score 6):

> The bolding was completely removed as unnecessary?

It was, as it was not only stylistically incorrect, but actually made the sentences harder to read for someone trying to help solve the problem.

> Is the above style of writing questions or answers wrong?

Yes, it is wrong. When you are creating a question or answer, it should be crafted so that it allows for the content to be the focus, not custom styles.

> Should I avoid bolding parts of a sentence, just to make a question or answer easily readable?

Yes, you should. It does not make it easier to read, and in the mind of many active readers may actually detract from being able to parse the post.

---

You should be using bold **sparingly**, only to emphasize one main point. Other than that, reserve bold for things like headings or description titles. Using too much bold can remove the effect of emphasis, as was the case with your use; in such cases, it will diminish the ability of the user to read what you have written.